# Fantasy film from the 70s or 80s involving a male lead being fed by a small person

Tags: story-identification, movie

I hold out little hope that anyone will know this, but it's worth a shot.

When I was young I remember watching a fantasy movie possibly made in the 1970's or 1980's. The only scene I really remember is of the main male lead sitting on the floor in a small house/hut in the forest. He was forced to sit because the house was too small to stand up in. He was being given a drink by small person like a Hobbit from *Lord of the Rings* or a Nelwyn from *Willow*. There is also a waterfall involved somewhere along the line, not 100% sure on that though. The male lead may have looked a little like [Lee Majors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_Majors).

- The movie was live action
- Medieval like setting
- The main character wore leather wrist bracers

Comment: What made it a fantasy movie? Was there magic? Dragons? Psychic powers?

Comment: Do you remember any names?  Any other scenes?  What was he given to eat and drink?  Do you remember anything in the house?  This was live action, not animated, right?

Comment: Was it a movie of Gulliver's Travels?

Comment: Was it *The Gnome-Mobile*?

Comment: I'm guessing, @FuzzyBoots, that it was Hobbit- or Nelwyn-like characters that give it the SFF vibe... :shrug:

Comment: {nods} But asking sometimes gets them to provide more details "Oh, yeah, there was magic. One of his team members could conjure fire and one of the other one had a bow that did rapid fire by repeatedly rewinding the footage of him shooting".

Comment: Voted as a dupe to a self-accept from some years back.

Comment: @hooch: Just letting you know that the Duplicate closing is not a censure, merely a way in which we track that [tag:story-identification] questions are talking about the same work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for ["Wizards of the Lost Kingdom"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wizards_of_the_Lost_Kingdom)?

Stuff that fits the description:

- Live action
- Medieval-ish setting
- The movie is from 1985
- One of the main characters wears leather wrist bracers:

[image]

The whole movie is on YouTube, the scene I think you're referring to is at about 43 minutes in (queued to that scene):

(This movie also got an excellent MST3K episode in one of the recent seasons.)

Comment: Thank you that is it. I've been trying to remember that movie for over 40 years. I guess I know what I will be watching this weekend. Takeaway, a few beers and a nostalgic movie : )

Answer (score 2):

There's a bit like that in the film version of The Neverending Story when Atreyu is tended by the gnomes after being rescued from the swamps of sadness by Falkor the Luck Dragon.